# Error while retrieving information from the server RPC:s-7:AEC-0 in Google play?

Tags: android

I made my test account to be synced in my device and ready to test the app.

While I am about to purchase the product in my app the google play prompts me to continue after entering credit card details.

After entering details of the card in the device it is showing error as

> Error while retrieving information from the server [RPC:s-7:AEC-0]

I am using Google play version 3.10.9

And i already tried to uninstall the update of google play removing my account and rebooting device but no use found the same error again and again could any one help me out of this

Comment: Hi, I am testing with Sandbox Google Buyer account and getting the same problem while entering all data...could you solved this issue.

Comment: Nopes Buddy @256 ..i think you manually do it by using desktop rather than using mobile for entering card info

Comment: Did anybody got through this issue. I am struck with this issue now. IT gives this message every time I enter my credit card details.

Answer (score 27):

Check if you are using latest version of Google Play.

***OR***

Following the steps below.

RPC:AEC:0 error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure.

Only possible way you can follow to get rid off this error is,

Go to settings >application > Play Store >Clear Data & Clear Cache.

Go to accounts >Google >Remove account.

Reboot device.

Again Settings>Account >Google >Log In.

Refer to [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-forum/224884-google-play-error-solution-rpc-s-5-aec-0-a-2.html) link

***OR***

Factory Reset is the last working option, if none of the above worked.

Comment: No need to remove your account or reboot the device, just clearing data worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for my an android nexus 5 andriod 4.4.4.

Comment: @Wyck did you try the other solutions?

Comment: @Wyck Also not working for me on a Nexus 5 with 4.4.4 I will try the factory reset.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. It is on happening when i am integrating in-app purchase in the new app. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had that problem too...turns out my credit card info on file needed updated to my new expiration date.

These instructions came from troubleshooting on my phone.

On a computer (not tablet or phone) sign into your [Google Wallet](http://wallet.google.com/manage), click Payment Methods then edit to edit info.  Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me when I encountered the same issue on my KitKat.
Remove your account from the device (Settings > Accounts > Google > Remove Account)

Remove the following data: 
Settings> Applications > All> Downloads > delete data.
Settings> Applications > All> Play Store> delete data.
Settings> Apps > All> Google Services Framework (or if they have it in English: Google Service Framework) > delete data.

Log in again and it was fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got similar error while using **in-app-purchase** in android. My mistake is I used wrong purchase id while instantiating the purchases.

```
public static final String PRODUCT_ID_ASTRO_Match = "android.test.product";//wrong id not in play store dev console
```

Replaced it with:

```
public static final String PRODUCT_ID_ASTRO_Match = "android.test.purchased";
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

on the BlueStacks emulator worked for me the following solution

Go to  ”**Settings**” -> “**Applications**” -> “**Manage Applications**” and select “**All**”

Go to “**Google Play Services Framework**” and select “**Clear Data**” & “**Clear Cache**” to remove all the data.

Go to “**Google Play Store**” and Select “**Clear Data**” & “**Clear Cache**” to remove all the data regarding Google Play Store.

Go to “**Settings**” -> “**Accounts**” -> “**Google**” -> Select “**Your Account**”

Go to “**Menu**” and Select “**Remove Account**”.

Now “**Restart**” your mobile device.

Go to “**Menu**” and “**Add Your Account**”.

and try to perform update or download.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - it sorted itself out in ~3 hours after I uploaded the app to the Play console. [According to Google](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html):

> Warning: It may take up to 2-3 hours after uploading the APK for
>   Google Play to recognize your updated APK version. If you try to test
>   your application before your uploaded APK is recognized by Google
>   Play, your application will receive a ‘purchase cancelled’ response
>   with an error message “This version of the application is not enabled
>   for In-app Billing.

While the message is not the same, I suspect the root cause to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Call to your bank and ask them to activate your card to internet-use. Thats what helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a country such as Argentina, you should call your bank and verify that your card is authorized for international purchases.  Certain credit cards in that country (such as pre-paid credit cards) are ONLY authorized for domestic purchases and purchases in bordering countries.  They DO work online, but the purchase must be from a bordering country.  What this means is that you may get this message because your card is valid but denied.  I know, because this has happened to me today.  Hopefully this helps someone else understand what their system is telling them.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the application on the test device and Google Play developer console really match.

I might have a bit of a special case but it might help someone: First, I had uploaded a package to Google Play that I had created with an ant build script. Second, on the test device, I debugged the same application (or so I thought). I got the *"Error while retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]"*, and logcat displayed:

> Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

The problem was that in the ant script, I have `aapt` command for modifying the package name. However, Eclipse does not run that command, so there was a package name mismatch between the applications in Google Play and the test device.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem `Error while retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-5:AEC-0]` was resolved after these steps:

1. Change password of your Google account via web.
2. Wait for a `Sign-in error` notification on your device.
3. Type new password and problem should disappeared.

Actually, this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

This error coud be also due to your google account already having Google Wallet/Google Checkout account linked. The existing account cannot be used for example it is a merchant account. Took me 20 minutes to figure out. Add new Google Account to your device, restart. While in Google Play switch to your new account. Buy your app/book/movie.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, if all other suggestions fail, then backup all your data and do a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

As I never had a paid app in my google account I don't think its related
to credit cards nor to cache clear in google services.

the trick that worked for me :

1. change the Android date back and forth once (manually).
2. re-sync my google account (manually).
3. go to Play app and download . all worked just fine this time.

I did notice a 2-3 hours idle will also fix it by itself.