# Google Play In-app purchase causing RPC:S-7:AEC-0

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

We are trying to get an in-app purchase in our Android app, and keep running into an issue.  Everything is set up on the console for my developer account, but I keep getting error RPC:S-7:AEC-0 on it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I also got the same problem before few months ago, I can also prefer you once go through with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814958/error-while-retrieving-information-from-the-server-rpcs-7aec-0-in-google-play
but in my case it couldn't help at that time, I suggest you should be change your whole code with given below link example: 

1) http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html
2) http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/
It will work for you. hope it will solve your problem.