# Android In App Billing - Error Retrieving Information From Server

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using Android in app billing for in app purchases.

In rare cases a number of my users are reporting this error:

> "Error retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]"

This is happening in production and not in testing. And I'm unable to reproduce this locally to debug.

What does this error mean and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [This Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814958/error-while-retrieving-information-from-the-server-rpcs-7aec-0-in-google-play)

> Check if you are using latest version of Google Play.
>
> OR
>
> Following the steps below.
>
> RPC:AEC:0 error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure.
>
> Only possible way you can follow to get rid off this error is,
>
> Go to settings >application > Play Store >Clear Data & Clear Cache.
>
> Go to accounts >Google >Remove account.
>
> Reboot device.
>
> Again Settings>Account >Google >Log In.
>
> Refer to this link
>
> OR
>
> Factory Reset is the last working option, if none of the above worked.

I believe that this might have the solution that you are looking for. Since the question mentioned that he/she noticed the issue with a test account, it may be that your customers are not using the latest version of Google play or that they need to clear their cache.

You can also [View this Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg69AGMS6Lw) titled "How to Fix " Error retrieving information from server [RPC:S-7:AEC-0] "

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that Google suspended the merchant account for the application.