# Error when I'm trying to rate app on google play

Tags: android, google-play

Here is information in toast:
Error retrieving information from server RPC: S-9 AEC-9
I tried to clear data in google play app, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @Igoranze yes, I tried to turn off application and device. The main point is that this issue is actual only for my app

Comment: Google says: **[1]** Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All
**[2]** Select "Clear Data" for Google Play Services and Google Service Framework
**[3]** Reboot the device

Comment: @Igoranze of corse I tried this. It doesn't help. It is reproducing on other users too. So it's a not device issue

Comment: Maby this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814958/error-while-retrieving-information-from-the-server-rpcs-7aec-0-in-google-play

Comment: I've already read this)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It happens because I'm beta-tester of this app. So beta testers can't rate th.